# comparison of two Strings doesn't work in android

Tags: java, android, string

here's my code, Eclipse doesn't show any errors, program's working fine, but it simply doesn't do exactly what i want:)

```
    View image_view_danger_rate = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.origin);
    View image_view_origin = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.danger_rate);

    String entry_tag = (String) descriptionResultView.findViewById(resID).getTag();

    String dangerous = "dangerous";
    String not_dangerous = "not_dangerous";

    if ( entry_tag == dangerous) {
        image_view_danger_rate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.attention);
    }else if ( entry_tag == not_dangerous) {
        image_view_danger_rate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.its_ok);
        image_view_origin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.artificial);
    }
```

The application should choose between two images to pop-up on the screen, depending on a tag stored in the xml file. 
So, if the tag says "dangerous", then should be shown the "attention"-image. 
If the tag says "not_dangerous", there should be the "its_ok"-image.

Now, displaying the images without an if-comparison works perfectly.

If i print out the tags as a string, it works, it prints correctly "dangerous" or "not_dangerous", depending on the tag.

But if there's a if-comparison as shown above, nothing happens, no image is shown.

Please anyone help!!=)

Comment: +1 for an elaborate and complete question.

Comment: This question has been asked on this site more times than I care to find.  Please use the search function.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Duplication is not necesarilly bad. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: @Woot4Moo Your link to the supposedly duplicate question does not even have to do with this question too.

Comment: @Marcelo even still how is this subtly different than any of the other examples on this site about people not knowing how to do string comparison in java?

Comment: well too late now to change my vote to close because of no new edit:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995918/java-string-comparison

Comment: let's not confuse `comparison` with `equality`

Answer (score 45):

Use `string1.equalsIgnoreCase("something)` or `.equals("Something");`

With `==` (for strings) in java you are comparing they are of same reference. Like you did is the test if both of them are strings objects.

Comment: I just learned something very important! =D it worked for me...thank you for this quick answer!

Answer (score 13):

In java, a==b is used to compare 2 references, not the objects themselves.

so if you have 2 strings that you want to compare, use the equals() method on String. for eg

```
boolean resultOfComparison=stringA.equals(stringB);
```

Comment: thanks to all of you, that was the solution!

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
entry_tag.equals(dangerous)
```

you're comparing actual String objects, not their content.
In Java, operators are not overloaded so **==** can't be used to compare strings.

Comment: thanks to all of you, that was the solution!

Answer (score 2):

In Java, if you want to compare Strings, you need to use `equals()`:

```
if (entry_tag.equals(dangerous)) {
}
```