# parsing empty string to integer in java

Tags: java, string, integer

```
if(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("SECNO").toString()!=null && jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("SECNO").toString().trim()!="")
                        appointment.mSecNo =Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("SECNO").toString());
                    else
                        appointment.mSecNo = -1;
```

In the previouse lines, when the value of `jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("SECNO").toString()` equales to '' it doesn't be caught by the if statement ..

and I get this error message .. `can't parse '' to integer`

Comment: **Checkout my one-line code answer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/77739302/4621922

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `==` or `!=` to compare strings in Java - it only compares the *references*, not the *contents* of the strings. Also, I doubt that `toString` would ever return null. I suspect you want:

```
Foo x = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("SECNO");
if (x != null && x.toString().trim().length() > 0)
```

(I don't know what the type of `jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("SECNO")` would be, hence the `Foo`.)

In this particular case I've used `length() > 0` to detect a non-empty string - but for more general equality, you'd want to use `equals`, so an alternative is:

```
if (x != null && !x.toString().trim().equals(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't compare Strings with `==`

See: [Java comparison with == of two strings is false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995918/java-string-comparison) , [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just,

```
int appointment.mSecNo = -1;

try {
    appointment.mSecNo = Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("SECNO").toString());
}catch(Exception e) {
    log.error(" your error message ");
}
```