# Converting String to Integers the safe way

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have a little method that amongst other things also converts a string into an integer. Since the string is a parameter of the method I want to make sure that that string is convertable. So I was just wondering what would be the safest and / or fastest way.

---

**Version A**: Just leave it as it is and take the risks (which I'm trying to avoid)

```
public static int stringToInt(String param) {
        return Integer.valueOf(param);
}
```

*(in terms of speed, what kind of difference would it make to version B and C?)*

---

**Version B**: Catch the exception

```
public static int stringToInt(String param) {
        try {
                return Integer.valueOf(param);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                return -1;
        }
}
```

---

**Version C**: Check each letter of the string to see, if it's a digit number or not

```
public static int stringToInt(String param) {
        for(char c : param.toCharArray()) {
                if(!Character.isDigit(c))
                        return -1;
        }
        return Integer.valueOf(param);
}
```

---

Note that the parameter has to be a positive number and the -1 is supposed to be the "error value" in my little program, in other words, all three versions of methods would work perfectally fine in my program.

I'm very open to any other suggestion you can give me, so feel free to create your own version, if you think yours is better.

Thank you very much for your support in advance.

Comment: The first version is only "risky" if an error is not the correct behavior, and if you don't want to catch a `NumberFormatException` somewhere higher up the change.  Throwing exceptions can be a perfectly healthy response to bad input.

Comment: In my opinion, the first one is the quickest, but it will throw an exception if you put a non numeric value. The second one is the best for me, as it has a catch to prevent exception from stopping your program. the last one, it just a long version of the second one.

Comment: version C fails on negative integers

Comment: @bengoesboom I mentioned that the input has to be positive

Comment: C is doing checking that A and B are already doing internally.  B is a good compromise between safety and speed.

Comment: @felixfritz if the input value must be positive, C produces different results than A and B. For an input of "-5", A and B return -5, C returns -1. Just food for thought.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I mentioned that the input has to be positive, so -1 (or pretty much any negative number) is going to be an "error number".

Comment: @bengoesboom: Very correct, but deceptive. Personally, I would sooner use a method which determines if the string is an integer first then do logic (ie. must be positive). It will be much clearer when you have to come back to it

Comment: @Craig I agree completely

Comment: You could use the option B but return an `OptionalInt` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, note that version `C` is not bulletproof: it would reject negative numbers, and would not catch numbers that are too large.

Version `B` is OK, yet it makes the caller change the coding style: rather than catching an error and processing it together with other errors, the caller would need to check for `-1` all the time. This may be suboptimal in situations where you read multiple integers, but the error processing does not depend on which particular one has failed. In addition, new coders using your API may forget to check for `-1`, and use the error code inadvertently.

That's why I would stay with the first option: the code using version `A` would look instantly familiar to anyone who knows Java API, without the need to learn what happens inside your function.

Comment: The OP notes that their actual method does "other things." It may not be so conveniently named as `stringToInt`. Explicitly declaring the thrown exception is likely a good idea unless the method name really is as clear as `stringToInt` (and of course javadoc to go with all of the above)

Answer (score 12):

Guava offers a utility method for this which returns null in case your String can't be parsed.

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#tryParse(java.lang.String)

```
Integer result = Ints.tryParse("1");  //returns 1
Integer result = Ints.tryParse("-1"); //returns -1
Integer result = Ints.tryParse("a");  //returns null
```

Comment: Note: Ints.tryParse(String string)  will throws NullPointerException if string is null.

Answer (score 3):

I believe a modified B to throw an exception rather than returning -1 will be the best choice. It is good to throw the exception up to the level, where it can be processed to send the proper response to the user. Returning a value like -1 will make your code error prone. Assume that a different programmer is consuming your method and he/she just have the signature of your method. So it is not clear from the signature what he/she should code to handle an exception or error scenario. But if you throw the exception and add it to your method declaration then it will enable the other programmer to consume your method properly alongwith the required exception handling. For me this looks the best:

```
public static int stringToInt(String param) throws NumberFormatException {
        try {
                return Integer.valueOf(param);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
               // return -1;
               throw e;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why catch the exception at all?

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 without any API:

```
 Optional.ofNullable(strNum)
         .map(Integer::valueOf).orElse(null);
```

Comment: If number starts with blank space we have errors: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "     1"

Answer (score 1):

```
public int stringToInt(String param) throws NumberFormatException {

    Optional.ofNullable(param.replaceAll("\\s+", ""))
         .map(Integer::valueOf).orElse(null);

/*
                      or

    Optional.ofNullable(param.replaceAll(" ", ""))
         .map(Integer::valueOf).orElse(null);

*/

}
```

use the replaceAll to replace white spaces the plus is cpu friendly even though seems not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of 2 answers to have it safe for nulls, empty or blank strings, and non numeric characters:

```
public static Integer safeStringToInt(String param) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(param).map(Ints::tryParse).orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone:
**Please Note:** StringUtils is from 'org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils'

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String nullable = "";
        Integer result = Optional.ofNullable("").filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank).map(Integer::valueOf).orElse(0);
        System.out.println("Result1: " + result);

        nullable = null;
        result = Optional.ofNullable(nullable).filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank).map(Integer::valueOf).orElse(0);
        System.out.println("Result2: " + result);

        nullable = "6";
        result = Optional.ofNullable(nullable).filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank).map(Integer::valueOf).orElse(0);
        System.out.println("Result3: " + result);

        nullable = "a";
        result = Optional.ofNullable(nullable).filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
                            .filter(NumberUtils::isCreatable).map(Integer::valueOf).orElse(0);
        System.out.println("Result4: " + result);
    }

Output:

Result1: 0
Result2: 0
Result3: 6
Result4: 0
```