# Converting a String to int. Set the int to 0 if String is null

Tags: java, android

I have a function which saves Android data in `sqlite` but I have to convert the `String` data to an `Integer`.

Whenever the `String` is `null` i would like to save as `0`

The following is my code which fails whenever the value is `null`

```
 int block_id = Integer.parseInt(jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("block_id"));
```

The `block_id` above is converted to an `Integer`.

This is what i have decided to do but still it fails to convert the string value to `0` whenever its `null`.

```
int block_id = Converttoint(jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("block_id"));
```

Then the function `convertToInt`

```
 public static Integer convertToInt(String str) {
    int n=0;
  if(str != null) {
      n = Integer.parseInt(str);
  }
    return n;
}
```

How should I change it, to make it work?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. I suspect your String isn't `null` but empty.

Comment: That code looks like it should work, although I'd return `int` instead of `Integer`, and change your method name to `convertToInt` (or `parseIntOrNull`)

Comment: After you checked if the string isnt't `null` I would also check if the string only contains numbers: `str.matches("[0-9]+");`. Or you simply catch the parse exception.

Comment: JSONObject jObj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
      int block_id = TextUtils.isEmpty(jObj.getString("block_id"))?0:jObj.getInt("block_id") ;  Try this

Comment: **Checkout my one-line code answer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/77739302/4621922

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of writing your own function use the inbuild construction of try-catch. Your problem is, that `jsonarray` or `jsonarray.getJSONObject(i)` or the value itself is a `null` and you call a method on null reference. Try the following:

```
int block_id = 0;        //this set's the block_id to 0 as a default.
try {
    block_id =  Integer.parseInt(jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("block_id"));    //this will set block_id to the String value, but if it's not convertable, will leave it 0.
} catch (Exception e) {};
```

In Java Exceptions are used for marking unexpected situations. For example parsing non-numeric `String` to a number (`NumberFormatException`) or calling a method on a `null` reference (`NullPointerException`). You can catch them in many ways.

```
try{
    //some code
} catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
    e.printStackTrace()     //very important - handles the Exception but prints the information!
} catch (NullPointerException e2) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or using the fact, that they all extend `Exception`:

```
try {
    //somecode
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace;
};
```

or since Java 7:

```
try {
    //somecode
} catch (NullPointerException | NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace;
};
```

*Note*

As I believe, that you'll read the answer carefully, please have in mind, that on StackOverflow we require the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which include the StackTrace of your exception. In your case it probably starts with the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Then, debugging is much easier. Without it, it's just guessing.

**Edit:** *According to the accepted answer*

The accepted answer is good and will work as long, as the value stored with key: `block_id` will be numeric. In case it's not numeric, your application will crash.

Instead of:

```
JSONObject jObj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
int block_id = jObj.has("block_id") ? jObj.getInt("block_id") : 0;
```

One should use:

```
int block_id;
try{
    JSONObject jObj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    block_id = jObj.has("block_id") ? jObj.getInt("block_id") : 0;
} catch (JSONException | NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Simply use the built-in method [`JSONObject#getInt(String)`](http://javadox.com/org.json/json/20151123/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt-java.lang.String-), it will automatically convert the value to an `int` by calling behind the scene `Integer.parseInt(String)` if it is a `String` or by calling `Number#intValue()` if it is a `Number`. To avoid an exception when your key is not available, simply check first if your `JSONObject` instance has your key using [`JSONObject#has(String)`](http://javadox.com/org.json/json/20151123/org/json/JSONObject.html#has-java.lang.String-), this is enough to be safe because a key cannot have a `null` value, either it exists with a non `null` value or it doesn't exist.

```
JSONObject jObj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
int block_id = jObj.has("block_id") ? jObj.getInt("block_id") : 0;
```

Answer (score 9):

There is one more way to do this apart from the methods given in rest of the answers.

```
String blockId=jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("block_id");
int block_id = blockId==null ? 0 :  Integer.parseInt(blockId);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can check for `NumberFormatException`. `Integer.parseInt()` will throw `NumberFormatException` for cases:

- `String` is `null`
- `String` is empty (`""`)
- `String` cannot be converted to `int` for any other reason (say `String` is `"aff"` or `"1.25"`)

Basically, it will handle all possible non-integer cases.

**Code Example:**

```
private static int convertStringToInt(String str){
    int x = 0;
    try{
        x = Integer.parseInt(str);
    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
        //TODO: LOG or HANDLE
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use following method,

```
String id = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("block_id")
int blockId = getBlockId(id);

@NonNull
private Integer getBlockId(String id) {
    Integer blockId= 0;
    try {
        blockId= Integer.parseInt(id);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return blockId;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
String toBeParsedStr="1234";
int parsedInt=toBeParsedStr!=null&&toBeParsedStr.matches("[0-9]+")?Integer.parseInt(toBeParsedStr):0;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
 int block_id = (jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).has(block_id)) ? jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("block_id") : 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `Integer.getInteger("30").intValue()`

Answer (score 2):

```
int block_id_0 = jObj.optInt("block_id");
```

The `ternary` condition and multiple code can simply be replaced with `optInt` function in a single line, which simply

1.) `return` the `default value` or `0` if no value is there (depends upon the variant you are using).

2.) Try to convert the value, if the value is available as `string`

3.) Simply **No null or NumberFormat exceptions at all** in case of missing key or value

Android docs

[`int optInt (String name)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optInt(java.lang.String))

[`int optInt (String name, int fallback)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optInt(java.lang.String,%20int))

Maven-Central

[`int optInt(String key, int defaultValue)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.json/json/20080701/org/json/JSONObject.java#JSONObject.optInt%28java.lang.String%29)

To get a specified default value if no value available

> Get an optional int value associated with a key, or the default if
>   there is no such key or if the value is not a number. If the value is
>   a string, an attempt will be made to evaluate it as a number.

```
jObj.optInt("block_id",defaultvalue);
```

or

To get a default value as 0 if no value available

> Get an optional int value associated with a key, or zero if there is
>   no such key or if the value is not a number. If the value is a string,
>   an attempt will be made to evaluate it as a number.

```
jObj.optInt("block_id");
```

e.g

```
int block_id = jObj.optInt("block_id",5);
```

`block_id` will be 5 if no key/value available

```
int block_id_0 = jObj.optInt("block_id");
```

`block_id_0` will be 0 if no key/value available

There are other variant of this function available for other datatypes as well , try the `docs` link above.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "...";
// suppose str becomes null after some operation(s).
int number = 0;
try
{
    if(str != null)
      number = Integer.parseInt(str);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    number = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice.. you could also write it like that

```
 public static Integer convertToInt(String str) {
    int n=0;
    if(str != null && str.length()>0) {
        n = Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
    return n;
}
```

but the try/catch method is way more effective and simple and will not cause a system exit if a letter get inside the String (just worth mentioning)

also, it is important to notice that writing the same equation like that:

```
if(str != null & str.length()>0) {}
```

or like that:

```
if(str.length()>0 && str != null) {}
```

can cause the operation to fail because it will try to count the String even if it is null

Hope I responded to all your questions

Answer (score -1):

Your function should work fine only when the param is an empty `string` instead of null
If the param is empty `string` ,`Integer.parseInt` would throw a `NumberFormatException` instead of return 0