# how to convert string to int - 0 when string is empty

Tags: scala

scala has the `mystring.toInt` method to convert string to int but this doesn't work on empty string. Is it possible to convert empty strings to a default int value? (say 0?)

Comment: `if (mystring.isEmpty) 0 else mystring.toInt`. I'm sure you realize the other edge cases there.

Comment: `util.Try{"".toInt}.getOrElse(0)`

Comment: **Checkout my one-line code answer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/77739302/4621922

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`String.toInt()`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#toInt:Int) as you know that you have something that is convertible to `int` :

> Parse as an Int (string must contain only decimal digits and optional
>   leading -).

So the method doesn't provide a default value.

Generally you can do this processing by checking that the String contains only digits in this way :

```
val a : Int = if (mystring.forall(Character.isDigit))  mystring.toInt else 0
```

But in your case (empty string) this is enough :

```
val a : Int =
      if (mystring.isEmpty) 0
      else mystring.toInt
```

Or you can also catch the exception such as  :

```
import scala.util.Try;
...
val a : Int = Try(mystring.toInt).getOrElse(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to always prepend whatever string you're given with "0" before calling toInt:

```
("0" + myString).toInt
```

When myString is "", the result is 0.

When myString is "123", the result is 123.

When myString is "123a", the result is an exception, since toInt does the checking for you.

Just out of curiosity to see how the string concatenation performs in comparison, using:

```
def makeAnInt(myString: String): Int = ("0" + myString).toInt
def makeAnInt2(mystring: String): Int = if (mystring.isEmpty) 0 else mystring.toInt
def makeAnInt3(mystring: String): Int = Try(mystring.toInt).getOrElse(0)
```

Generated:

```
1M calls with "":
("0" + myString).toInt -> 250ms
if (mystring.isEmpty) 0 else mystring.toInt -> 156ms
Try(mystring.toInt).getOrElse(0) -> 1481ms

1M calls with "123":
("0" + myString).toInt -> 251ms
if (mystring.isEmpty) 0 else mystring.toInt -> 188ms
Try(mystring.toInt).getOrElse(0) -> 198ms
```