# Java 8 Optional parse string to int or if is null and set default empty string

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to parse `string` to `int` and set as default an empty `string` if the string is `null` with lambda. Here is my code:

```java
Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();
String myString = "Some String"; //can be also null

myMap.put("myData", Optional.ofNullable(myString).map(Integer::parseInt).orElse(""));
...
```

The Problem is that i should to set an `Integer` in `.orElse()` as default but I need to set and empty `string`. I know I can do this with java like this:

```java
myMap.put("myData", StringUtils.isEmpty(myString) ? "" : Integer.parseInt(myString));
```

but I want do that with lambda.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: You want to insert both `Integer`s and `String`s into the map? Mixed types are icky. I would suggest making it a `Map<String, Integer>`. If `myString` is null then either insert `null` or simply omit the key/value pair from the map.

Comment: @JohnKugelman thank you for your suggestion but i need that map to be like in the example for some reasons. That's why i asked for that. Maybe you have some ideas?

Comment: You could explicitly set type for `map(..)` to Object with `Optional.ofNullable(myString).<Object>map(Integer::parseInt)` which would result in `Optional<Object>` and let you use `.orElse("")`. But honestly I am not sure this code is going in right direction... It feels like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: @Pshemo thank you. Thats seems to be the only one option or there are other option?

Comment: When you say “*but i need that map to be like in the example for some reasons*” are those “some reasons” in the same league as the “*but I want do that with lambda*” requirement?

Comment: @Holger yes,but i solved already my problem, thank you for taken time.

Comment: **Checkout my one-line code answer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/77739302/4621922

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s fairly straightforward. We just need to tell the stream pipeline to consider the `Integer` an `Object`, not an `Integer`. And oh yes, then the string needs to hold a number when it is not null.

```
    Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    String myString = "53"; //can be also null

    myMap.put("myData",
            Optional.ofNullable(myString)
                    .map(s -> (Object) Integer.valueOf(s))
                    .orElse(""));
    
    System.out.println(myMap);
```

This outputs:

> {myData=53}

And if I change this line:

```
    String myString = null; //can be also non-null
```

> {myData=}

You do not need to use an `Optional`, and some would prefer that you don’t. Here’s a variant without it:

```
    myMap.put("myData", myString == null ? "" : Integer.valueOf(myString));
```

The result is the same as before. Do you agree that it’s simpler?