# if () not working

Tags: java, android

This is my code:

```
Log.d("inf", loader);
if (loader == "Klasse"){
    Log.d("inf", "Klasse yes");
    OPTS = new String[] { //Something };
} else {
    Log.d("inf", "Klasse no");
    OPTS = new String[] { //Something };
}
```

In the first Line, the Output is exactly "Klasse" but the next output is everytime "Klasse no". The loader String is set as follows:

```
String loader = "";
Bundle exta = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(exta !=null) {
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(exta.getString("json"));
            loader = exta.getString("order");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Do you guys have any Idea whats wrong?

Comment: String comparison should be done using `.equals`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string comparison?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995918/java-string-comparison)

Comment: @blackbelt isn't that deprecated? (Just a question, i'm an 'enthusiast programmer', not a professional)

Comment: @JonSkeet no, he didn't know that.

Comment: there is almost 1 question everyday with the same thing. `==` instead of `equals()`

Comment: @Styler2go You don't have to be sorry. I was just saying generally. :-)

Comment: @11684 No, it is not. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: @11684: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: he did not know it was about string comparing. @Jon

Comment: @11684: That's because he didn't perform adequate diagnostic steps before posting, IMO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `==` comparison operator compares references rather than values. You need to compare the values and so need to use the `equals()` method.

```
if (loader.equals("Klasse"))
```

Comment: Good. Now i know i'm a little retarded :D Normally im using C# and so on.. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, this is the classic C#/Java mistake.

Comment: Or you could 'intern()' them first.

Comment: @11684 You are joking aren't you?

Comment: @David I thought the jvm had a string pool. Wouldn't references be equal if they were in a string pool?

Comment: @skaz only if the strings had been interned.

Comment: I said you could, nou that it is a good solution. I always want to know such facts, so why shouldn't I say?

Comment: Yes, its everytime interesting to see other ways, like "How i could have done it"

Comment: @11684: If you're going to include an option which you *know* isn't generally a good one, it's worth saying so when you mention it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between identity (`==`) and equality (`equals()`). Identity tests for whether or not the object pointers are the same so almost never is correct. Equality tests whether or not the object "values" are the same, so it's almost always what you need instead.

Comment: Why does, for example, the Language C# use == for equality too?

Comment: @Styler2go Ask yourself when was the last time you want to compare two string references for identity?

Comment: I think in C# the Java `==` would be `===`, isn't it that?

Answer (score 0):

String comparison should always be done with the equals method.

```
if(loader.equals("Klasse")) { .... }
```

This is because String is a class and by using '==' you check whether they are the same object, which they a not. Equals checks that the strings you are comparing are equal.

Answer (score 0):

if == or === does not work, use .equals