# Check if a variable is equal to a string

Tags: java, string, equals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
>   [Java string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995918/java-string-comparison)

```
import java.util.*;

public class whatever
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner test = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input: ");
        String name = test.nextLine();

        if (name == "Win")
        {
            System.out.println("Working!");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Something is wrong...");
        }

        System.out.println("Value is: " + name);

    }

}
```

The code above is pretty self-explanatory. I'm assuming `==` can only be used for numbers? I want "Working!" to be printed.

Answer (score 9):

`==` compares objects by reference.

To find out whether two different `String` instances have the same value, call `.equals()`.

Comment: Just to mention, "Win".equals(name) will be a more secure solution in case if name is null.

Answer (score 5):

You should use

```
if (name.equals("Win")){
    System.out.println("Working!");
}
```

Edit Suggested By RC in comments to avoid null problems:

```
if ("Win".equals(name)){
    System.out.println("Working!");
}
```

Comment: `"Win".equals(name)` so if `name` is `null`, no worries

Comment: I'd recommend ignoring case.  Should "win" be less a victory than "Win" or "wIn" or "wiN"?