# String comparison doesn't succeed and calculating total as 0

Tags: java, inheritance

If the user choose a class from the one's listed in `LabCourse` (BIO, CIS...) it should give the total plus lab charge (50), but my code is always executing total as 0 and printing the `"This class don't have lab"` message

What could the problem be?

CollegeCourse.java

```
public class CollegeCourse
{
String name;
int num;
int crd;
double fee;
double total;

public CollegeCourse(String n)
  {
  name =n;
  }

public double computetotal(double fee, int crd)

    {
          fee = fee * crd;
          System.out.println("Total is $" + fee);
          this.fee=fee;
          return fee;
    }

public String getname()
  {
       return name;
  }

public int getnum()
  {
       return num;
  }

public int getcrd()
  {
       return crd;
  }
    // public double getfee()
  // {
  //       return fee;
  // }
}
```

LabCourse.java

```
public class LabCourse extends CollegeCourse
{
 double total=0;

public LabCourse(String name, double fee)
{
  super(name);
}

public void computetotal(String name)
{
   super.computetotal(fee, crd);
   if((name == "BIO") || (name == "CHM") || (name == "CIS") || (name =="PHY"))
   {
      total = fee+ 50;
      System.out.println("Total with lab is: " + total);
   }
   else 
      System.out.println("This class don't have Lab");
}
}
```

UseCourse.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UseCourse
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
   String name;
   int num;
   int crd;
   double fee;

   Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print("Enter Department name: ");
   name = inputDevice.next();
   System.out.print("Enter Course number: ");
   num= inputDevice.nextInt();
   System.out.print("Enter Credit hours: ");
   crd = inputDevice.nextInt();
   System.out.print("Enter fee: ");
   fee = inputDevice.nextDouble();
   System.out.print("\n\n"); 

   CollegeCourse course = new CollegeCourse(name);
   course.computetotal(fee, crd);

   LabCourse full = new LabCourse(name, fee);
   full.computetotal(name);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are classes. You should not use `==` to compare classes (unless you want to check whether they are the exact same object (not just, in this case, the same text))

Some IDEs (e.g. [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/)) will give you a warning when you try to use `==` on strings.

Try `System.out.println(new String("ABC") == "ABC");` - this will print `false`.

Use `equals` instead:

```
if (name.equals("BIO") || name.equals("CHM") ||
    name.equals("CIS") || name.equals("PHY"))
```

A simpler option with regular expressions:

```
if (name.matches("BIO|CHM|CIS|PHY"))
```

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29).

**EDIT:**

Another problem is that you're never setting up `LabCourse.fee`, but you use it here:

```
super.computetotal(fee, crd);
```

So set it up in the constructor:

```
public LabCourse(String name, double fee)
{
  super(name);
  this.fee = fee; // or add this as a parameter to CollegeCourse's constructor
}
```

But, since `computetotal` overwrites the fee, multiple calls to it may not quite work as you want, so you may want to pass it as a parameter to `computetotal` instead:

```
public class LabCourse extends CollegeCourse
{
  ...
  public void computetotal(String name, double fee)
  ...
}
```

Which leads to the question - does it make sense to have `fee` be a class variable? Or maybe it would make more sense to just put the code from `computetotal` in the constructor and get rid of `computetotal` or something along those lines. The same for `name`.

Comment: I got it...
Thanks for your time

Comment: I still have issues because fee still not inherited by LabCourse.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but where exactly do you set the fee of the labcourse? And yeah, comparing strings must be done with String.equals() and not with ==.

[Java comparison with == of two strings is false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995918/java-string-comparison)