# How do I display numbers in JTextField after tap on any number from calculator?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I know that I should use "actionlistener", so I suppose that the below code should work but it doesn't.

```
if (e.getSource() == "but0") { // but0 is name of button with number "0"
    String aaa = but0.getText();
    field.setText(aaa);
}
```

Comment: did you checked what but0.gettext() returns?

Comment: [Don't compare strings with '=='](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995918/java-string-comparison).

Comment: How can i check it? I'm new in Java, i tryind to create simple calculator. I think that getText() method must return "0" from the 
JButton but0=new JButton("0");

Answer (score 0):

The button caption should be read using .equals(). == won't work here.

Try `e.getSource().getText().equals("0")`

Or compare the object directly as e.getSource()==but0

Comment: no, "==" works, for example functionality of button "C" (Clean) work correctly with next code

if (e.getSource()==clean){
   field.setText(null);}

wen I tap on "C" button all text is deleted from JTextfield!! but I can input any text only from keyboard

Comment: @redavlr You should only ever compare strings for equality using `equals()`, not `==`, because `==` will only work with string literals known at compile time.

Comment: clean is your button's caption?? I am sure it is the object name. Fo C you are comparing object not string. e.getSource() gives action button.

Comment: Yes, but but0 is also object name for button 0 ( ... Can somebody write part of code which create jtextfield, one button and alction listener method which help to display value of this button in textfield after tapping? (( need help)

Comment: I have edited my answer. and if but0 is name of the object than you should not compare it as =="but0"; just do ==but0.

Answer (score 0):

Add button in array when creating it

```
ArrayList<JButton> buttonA = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<=9;i++) {
 String num_ = String.valueOf(i);
 JButton button = new JButton(num_);
 button.setName(num_);
 buttonA.add(button);
  // do remaining stuff
}
```

In action

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   if(buttonA.contains(e.getSource())) {
            JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
            display.setText(display.getText() + btn.getName());
   } else if() { // operations like +,- etc.,

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDocs, on `java.awt.event.EventObject`:

> `public Object getSource()`
>
> The object on which the Event initially occurred.

Instead of comparing with a String, try comparing with the button itself:

```
if (e.getSource() == but0) {
    String aaa = but0.getText();
    field.setText(aaa);
}
```