# How to compare user input to an instance variable of all objects from a class

Tags: java, class, oop, object

So, I'm trying to compare a string to an instance variable of another class, and I can't think of a way to do this for all objects of the said class.
  I know for sure that if the method where this occurs is running, I have 4 objects of the class that contains the instance variable.
  The goal is to compare the string the user gives me, and if it is equal to the one of a previously defined object, change another instance variable in that object.
  In sudo-code it would be something like this:

```
if (colourInput == colourofAnyObjectOfTheClass)
   sizeOfThatObject = sizeInput;
else
   new Object(colourInput, sizeInput);
```

And I've previously defined what colourInput and sizeInput are.
 How can I go about implementing this in Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string comparison?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995918/java-string-comparison)

Answer (score 1):

[When comparing Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995918/java-string-comparison), you should use the [String#equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method, not the `==` operator.

```
if (colourofAnyObjectOfTheClass.equals(colourInput)) {
    sizeOfThatObject = sizeInput;
} else {
    new SomeObject(colourInput, sizeInput);
}
```

Comment: and always nice to put the constant in front

Comment: Why is using .equals() a better solution?

Comment: Because `.equals()` checks the **contents** of the objects for equality, while the `==` operator checks whether the variables refer the same object in the memory. Check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995918/java-string-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating some sort of repository of instances of your class that is class which will manage creation of object so it can keep track of them.

```
class MyEntityRepository {
    private List<MyEntity> entities;

    public MyEntity createOrUpdate(String color, Integer size) {
         MyEntity entity = findByColor(color);
         if (entity != null) {
             entity.setSize(size); 
         } else {
             entity = new MyEntity(color, size);
             entities.add(entity);
         }
         return entity;
    } 

    private MyEntity findByColor(String color) { ... }
}
```

If you have a lot of entities you may create some sort of index, for example store `Map<String, MyEntity>` which maps keys to entities and use it to speed up search.