# Comparing String Array value to JavaFX Combo box value does not evaluate to true

Tags: java, javafx

I have a loop to check the values in an array and compare them to the value in a Combo box.  For some reason, even when they match, a compare does not evaluate to true.

Here is the loop, with System output added for troubleshooting:

```
System.out.println("Race Changed, setting new attribute min/maxes");
                int raceIndex = -1;

                for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
                    System.out.println("RaceCheck index i="
                                      + Integer.toString(i)
                                      + " raceIndex="
                                      + Integer.toString(raceIndex)
                                      + " miscData.raceData[i].raceName="
                                      + miscData.raceData[i].raceName 
                                      + " cboRace.getValue()=" 
                                      + cboRace.getValue()
                                      + " match found="
                                      + (miscData.raceData[i].raceName == cboRace.getValue()));
                    System.out.println("|"+miscData.raceData[i].raceName+"|");
                    System.out.println("|"+cboRace.getValue()+"|");
                    if (miscData.raceData[i].raceName == cboRace.getValue()) {
                        raceIndex = i;
                    }       
                }

                if (raceIndex < 0) {
                    // race was not found, default to Human
                    System.out.println("Race " + cboRace.getValue() + " was not found in racedata");
                    raceIndex = 0;
                }
```

And here is the output:

```
Race Changed, setting new attribute min/maxes
RaceCheck index i=0 raceIndex=-1 miscData.raceData[i].raceName=Human cboRace.getValue()=Dwarf match found=false
|Human|
|Dwarf|
RaceCheck index i=1 raceIndex=-1 miscData.raceData[i].raceName=Elf cboRace.getValue()=Dwarf match found=false
|Elf|
|Dwarf|
RaceCheck index i=2 raceIndex=-1 miscData.raceData[i].raceName=Dwarf cboRace.getValue()=Dwarf match found=false
|Dwarf|
|Dwarf|
RaceCheck index i=3 raceIndex=-1 miscData.raceData[i].raceName=Ork cboRace.getValue()=Dwarf match found=false
|Ork|
|Dwarf|
RaceCheck index i=4 raceIndex=-1 miscData.raceData[i].raceName=Troll cboRace.getValue()=Dwarf match found=false
|Troll|
|Dwarf|
Race Dwarf was not found in racedata
```

I am using Java 7 Update 40, with JavaFX for the combo box.  How can I get the matching values to evaluate to true when comparing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java (so in JavaFX too) `Object`s should be compared with `.equals()` method instead of `==` operator. `==` operator compares the objects by references, in practice by their memory addresses. Since `String`s are also objects, use

```
if (miscData.raceData[i].raceName.equals(cboRace.getValue())) {
    raceIndex = i;
}
```

For reference follow [Java string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995918/java-string-comparison).