# How Java concatenates String with boolean?

Tags: java

I fail to understand the outputs below:

```
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)+"a");  ->truea

System.out.println(s1==s2+"a");         ->false
```

Where s1 & s2 are declared as same String "abc" i.e `String s1="abc"; String s2="abc";`

Comment: this question has literally been asked hundreds of times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java comparison with == of two strings is false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995918/java-comparison-with-of-two-strings-is-false)

Comment: @Woot4Moo This is about operator precedence, not string equality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s1==s2+"a"
```

means the same as

```
s1==(s2+"a")
```

because `==` has lower [precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) than `+`.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) the **`+`** operator has higher precedence than `equality` check.

Answer (score -3):

Because s1 is one string object while s2 is another string object. They have different memory addresses.

Comment: It is not really true. String literals are stored in small tables, and new variables are given access to those. It means that if you declare it like new String("abc") == new String("abc"), it will give false, but in the OP question it should give true.

Comment: @ArtemMoskalev it definitely should not.

Comment: @Woot4Moo, String a = "abc"; String b = "abc"; a == b gives true. You can check.