# ZXing SCAN_RESULT if statements

Tags: java, android, if-statement, zxing

this is my first question on stack**overflow**!

I am using Eclipse with Android Development Tools. I have copied the code from [GitHub - ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent) to scan a QR code using Barcode Scanner (many of you have seen this code before, I'm sure):

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent,0);
}
```

I am able to get the Barcode Scanner started and it returns results in the `onActivityResult()` method.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        if (requestCode == 0)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

                // Handle successful scan
                if(contents == "1") 
                {
                    contentsLat = contents;
                }
                else if(contents == "0")
                {
                    contentsRow = contents;
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Code Not Recognized\n"+contents+"\n1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            {
                // Handle cancel
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unsuccessful Scan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the `else` statement is always executed...unless I explicitly equate `contents` to `1`. Below is a link to the screenshot (I don't have embedded image privileges yet) of the `else` body being executed and the toast clearly indicates that `contents=1`. What have I done wrong? Did I miss something?

Thanks everybody.

Comment: When comparing strings **ALWAYS** use .equals so try if(contents.equals("1"))

Comment: Thanks Sean. That's the fix. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)!

I have seen this is a very common issue in new Java programmmers :), for String comparison we must use the `equals()` method.

Change your code to:

```
 // Handle successful scan
                if(contents.equals("1")){
                    contentsLat = contents;
                }
                else if(contents.equals("0")){
                    contentsRow = contents;
                }
```

More info:

**[Java comparison with == of two strings is false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995918/java-comparison-with-of-two-strings-is-false)**

[**The equals() Method**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html)