# Why doesn't my string comparison with == work?

Tags: java

I have this, in my `onPostExecute` :

```
    String test = currentActivity.getClass().getSimpleName();
    if(test == "SplashScreen"){
        Log.e("OK",test);

    } else {
        Log.e("OK",test);

    }
```

The problem is, the value of test is "SplashScreen" (that we can see with the log), but the code never goes in the `if`, only in the `else`.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Have you tried using `test.equals("SplashScreen")`?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995918/java-comparison-with-of-two-strings-is-false

Answer (score 3):

As the others had already said you can not use the == operator on strings.
The reason for this is that strings are objects and not primitive datatypes. 
With that said the == operator will check if the two strings has the same memory point in the memory if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

use `equals` to compare strings:

```
 if(test.equals("SplashScreen"){ 
  Log.e("OK",test);

 } else {
    Log.e("OK",test);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use == on strings. You should use:

```
"SplashScreen".equals(test)
```

Test might be null, it is better to call equals() on "SplashScreen" since you know that it is no null.

Comment: yes, of course... i forgot it.... i need to stop Php :D thx

Comment: @Myste - and you need to start searching for answers before you ask Questions.  This one has been asked thousands of times before.

Answer (score 0):

Don't compare string with `==` use `.equals()`

```
String test = currentActivity.getClass().getSimpleName();
if(test.equals("SplashScreen")){
    Log.e("OK",test);

} else {
    Log.e("OK",test);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use equalsIgnoreCase(String string).

```
 String test = currentActivity.getClass().getSimpleName();
if(test.equalsIgnoreCase("SplashScreen")){
    Log.e("OK",test);

} else {
    Log.e("OK",test);

}
```