# Comparing Mather groups returns unexpected value

Tags: java, regex

The values of `zerosMatcherNext.group(1)` and `zerosMatcher.group(1)` are being evaluated as String with value `0` but the comparison `zerosMatcherNext.group(1) ==  zerosMatcher.group(1)` returns `false`. What is the explanation for such a strange behavior?

**UPDATE:**

but `zerosMatcherNext.group(1).equals(zerosMatcher.group(1))` returns `true`

Comment: I blame it on the code you didn't post.

Answer (score 1):

String comparison should be made with [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

```
    new String("0") == new String("0"); // return false
    new String("0").equals(new String("0"); // returns true
```

[Java comparison with == of two strings is false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995918/java-comparison-with-of-two-strings-is-false)

Comment: @RCola `===` does not exist in Java.