# How can one determine the index of a character clicked within a TextArea in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, textarea, mouseevent

I want to write an event handler for a TextArea which upon the user clicking on the TextArea can determine the index of the character clicked and act based on this.

The suggested solutions in [Get cursor position (in characters) within a text Input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field) are Javascript instead of Java and do not answer how to convert mouse click coordinates to a text index.

Currently I have:

```
private EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

            int x=(int)mouseEvent.getX();
            int y=(int)mouseEvent.getY();

            String type=mouseEvent.getEventType().toString();

            if(type=="MOUSE_CLICKED")
            {
                System.out.println("Mouse clicked over textarea at x="+x+" y="+y);

                // TODO

                // determine text index under click
            }
        }
    };
```

---

```
TextArea my_textarea=new TextArea();
my_textarea.setOnMouseClicked(mouseHandler);
```

Comment: Please show some code that proves your attempt on the problem

Comment: Can downvoters explain the reason of their downvoting? The textarea mouseevent etc in this question is in context of JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
 private EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

            int x=(int)mouseEvent.getX();
            int y=(int)mouseEvent.getY();

            String type=mouseEvent.getEventType().toString();

            if(type.equals("MOUSE_CLICKED"))
            {
                System.out.println("Mouse clicked over textarea at x="+x+" y="+y);

                System.out.println("Caret position: "+my_textarea.getCaretPosition());
            }

        }

    };
```

...

```
TextArea my_textarea=new TextArea();
my_textarea.setOnMouseClicked(mouseHandler);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and Java! Comparing String values with "==" operator is somewhat erroneous see [Java String comparison discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995918/java-string-comparison). Also there is no need to get the String representation of event type just do `if ( mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED )`. It is more type safer.

Comment: I always mess this up. I had several bugs because of this already but for some reason I cannot learn to use .equals().